# Adobe Flash output not showing text

Tags: flash, animation, flash-cs6

I created an animation with action script 3.0, usually I export it into GIF and all goes well, but when I export into AVI text does not appear only the object and background that comes with the sound

> 1. so is there a solution to my problem ?
> 2. is there any text formatting for AVI output ?

note: Im using text tool with motion tween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, it appears that TLF text goes invisible in AVI exports.

Motion Tween should build tween objects for you; edit those tween objects and check to see if your text is TLF Text or Classic Text.  If it's TLF you will want to either:

(a) Convert your TLF text to Classic Text.  It will likely change your positioning, so it might not be desirable for your needs.

Or:

(b) Use Ctrl-B to Break Apart your text. This will preserve most of your layout without affecting text placement as much.

Comment: thanks dre for your answer im so much appreciate it but i've solved this problem before u post an answer, and im using answer a its work nicely